# Unable to ssh over internet

Tags: network, ssh

I'm trying to ssh into a Linux server I run and I'm having a weird issue where I can ssh over the internal network but not over the internet. Over the internet, the ssh connection hangs at "connecting over port 22"

I have another computer (PC) that can successfully ssh into the server over internal and internet, so the problem is not with the server config.

To summarize:

```
# PC
ssh -i key [user]@[internal ip] 
> Works

ssh -i key [user]@[internet ip] 
> Works

# MacBook
ssh -i key [user]@[internal ip] 
> Works

ssh -i key [user]@[internet ip] 
> Fails
```

Does anyone know what the issue might be?

Update:
If I start an EC2 instance, I can SSH from my macbook into EC2, then from EC2 into my server. But trying to SSH directly from the macbook into the server still fails.

Comment: As a first test to be sure you are comparing comparable situations, could you run on your 2 ssh clients: `route get [Internet IP]`?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could you run `ssh` in verbose mode: `ssh -v -i key [user]@[internet ip]` on your Mac and post the output (you may want to redact username and IP address with [user] and [internet ip])?